# Getting non-duplicate random numbers in discord.py

Tags: python, random, discord, discord.py

I've been working on a command that returns a random string using a dictionary and the random library:

```
import random
randnum = random.randint(0,5)

words = {1:"random text" 2:"random text2" 3:"random text3" 4:"random text4" 5:"randomtext5"}

def getrandom():
    randomtext = words[randnum]
    return randomtext
```

But whenever I use the command it returns the same text since I'm getting the same number over and over again, I also tried using the `random.sample` method, but I'm getting the same results, I don't have much experience with this library,
Is there any way for me to get a random non-duplicate number? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you intentionally returning `randnum` instead of `randomtext` in your function?

Comment: Thanks for the point out, It wasn't intentional The ```randomtext``` got replaced with ```randnum``` when I was editing the question, it's fixed now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the random number inside the getrandom() method.

```
import random

words = {1:"random text" 2:"random text2" 3:"random text3" 4:"random text4" 5:"randomtext5"}

def getrandom():
    randnum = random.randint(0,5)
    randomtext = words[randnum]
    return randomtext
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the random number in your function so it generates a new number each time it is called:

```
def getrandom():
    randnum = random.randint(0,5)
    randomtext = words[randnum]
    return randomtext
```